# Gulp build issues

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, gulp

Project type: WordPress on Google App Engine.

**Problem**

Running Gulp and have a few errors stopping my projects from being ready to view propelry in the browser.

I run gulp in my project and get the following log of erros:

```
[14:34:53] Using gulpfile C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\gulpfile.js
[14:34:53] Starting 'clean'...
[14:34:53] Finished 'clean' after 46 ms
[14:34:53] Starting 'default'...
[14:34:53] Starting 'build'...
[14:34:53] Starting 'wiredep'...
[14:34:58] Finished 'default' after 5.69 s
[14:34:59] Finished 'wiredep' after 6.06 s
[14:34:59] Starting 'styles'...
'main.less' wasn't found. Tried - C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\assets\styles\main.less,main.less in file C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\assets\styles\editor-style.scss line no. 1
'pages/_stories.less' wasn't found. Tried - C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\assets\styles\pages\_stories.less,pages\_stories.less in file C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\assets\styles\main.scss line no. 33
[14:34:59] Finished 'styles' after 711 ms
[14:34:59] Starting 'jshint'...

assets\scripts\referral.js
  line 801   col 14  'attachClickHandlers' was used before it was defined.
  line 907   col 14  'attachChangeHandlers' was used before it was defined.
  line 1039  col 14  'initSelect2Lists' was used before it was defined.
  line 1052  col 14  'initDatePicker' was used before it was defined.
  line 1068  col 14  'initProgressList' was used before it was defined.
  line 1187  col 14  'previewImage' was used before it was defined.
  line 1207  col 14  'ping' was used before it was defined.
  line 1295  col 14  'updateConfirmationPage' was used before it was defined.
  line 1455  col 14  'updateAccompanimentSelectList' was used before it was defined.
  line 1511  col 14  'doesValidate' was used before it was defined.
  line 1551  col 14  'convertReferralToJsonString' was used before it was defined.
  line 1602  col 14  'onSubmitSuccess' was used before it was defined.
  line 1627  col 14  'onSubmitFailure' was used before it was defined.

  ‼  13 warnings

[14:35:00] Finished 'jshint' after 561 ms
[14:35:00] Starting 'scripts'...
[14:35:01] Finished 'scripts' after 508 ms
[14:35:01] Starting 'fonts'...
[14:35:01] Starting 'images'...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn C:\dev\projects\romac-website\web\app\themes\romac\node_modules\optipng-bin\vendor\optipng.exe ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

So with my limited understanding it seems reading the error log suggests the following issues with my project build:

1. Starting 'styles' ---> Problem finding .less files
2. Starting 'jshint' ---> Not happy with some code in file referral.js
3. Starting 'images' ---> problem with node module optipng-bin

When I then run local server (app engine) I get the favicon load in and nothing else, just a blank page.

**Questions**

Is my initial understanding of the errors correct? and how can I resolve??

PS let me know if I need to edit this with more info.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command  "npm rebuild optipng-bin". This is mostly due to the corrupt package "optipng-bin"